# React Native - How do you create a vertical overlay?

Tags: react-native

I was just wondering if it was possible, in React Native, to create a vertical overlay ; by that, I mean being on a page and when swiping down, an overlay comes down, covering the page, with various information on it (and the same when swiping up, an overlay coming from the bottom). I wanted to use react-native-swiper at first, but the vertical swiping is not compatible with Android.. So if anyone has another solution to offer, be my guest ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check [react-native-parallax-view](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-parallax-view) hope this can help you.

EDIT

example:

```
return (
    <View style={[{ flex: 1 }]}> {/* add parent container and then ParallaxView as specified in documentation */}
        <ParallaxView
            backgroundSource={require('image!backgroundImage')}
            windowHeight={300}
            header={(
                <Text style={styles.header}>
                    Header Content
                </Text>
            )}
            scrollableViewStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
            >
            <View>
            // ... scrollview content
            </View>
        </ParallaxView>
    </View>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check that now !

Comment: Hey, do you have any examples on how to make it work ? I'm having a bit of trouble with it and I can't seem to find some clear examples online..